# Cadastro infinito de cliente

Tags: python-3.x

Estou estudando Python e resolvi criar um pequeno programa de cadastro via terminal, mas não consigo fazer um loop que passe por todas as opções, o programa fica interminavelmente no cadastro de cliente.

Segue código:

```
#cadastro de cliente em programacao procedural

clientes = []
n_clientes = 1

def menu() :
    option = int(input('''
[1] - Cadastrar cliente
[2] - Consultar Clientes
[3] - Editar Cliente
[4] - Sair do programa
'''))

    return option

def cadastra_cliente() :
    cliente_nome = input('Digite o nome do cliente: ')
    cliente_cep = input('Digite o cep do cliente: ')
    cliente_telefone = input('Digite o telefone do cliente: ')
    clientes_dados = (cliente_nome,cliente_cep,cliente_telefone)
    clientes.append(clientes_dados)
    print(clientes)
    print('Cliente adicionado')

def mostrar_cliente() :
    print(f'''
    Nome: {clientes[0]}
    Cep: {clientes[1]}
    Telefone: {Clientes[2]}''')


def programa() :

    option = menu()
    while True:
        if option == 1 :
            cadastra_cliente()
        if option == 2 :
            mostrar_cliente()
programa()
```

Poderiam me ajudar? Eu consegui fazer isso em Java uma vez com `do {} while`, mas não consigo fazer no Python.

---

Mais uma dúvida somente!

NO java quando fiz um programa similar, para alterar o cadastro eu tinha a seguinte estrutura.

```
public static void editarCadastro() {
    System.out.print("Informe o codigo que gostaria de atualizar: \n");
    int posicaoPessoa = Entrada.leiaInt();
    String pessoa[] = listaDePessoas.get(posicaoPessoa);

    if (pessoa != null) {
        System.out.println("Nome: '" + pessoa[0] + "'");
        pessoa[0] = Entrada.leiaString();
        System.out.println("CEP: '" + pessoa[1] + "'");
        pessoa[1] = Entrada.leiaString();
        System.out.println("Endereço : '" + pessoa[2] + "'");
        pessoa[2] = Entrada.leiaString();
        System.out.println("E-mail: '" + pessoa[3] + "'");
        pessoa[3] = Entrada.leiaString();
        System.out.println("Telefone: '" + pessoa[4] + "'");
        pessoa[4] = Entrada.leiaString();

        System.out.println("Pessoa atualizada");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Pessoa não encontrada");
    }
}
```

Eu ando com bastante dificuldade pra trabalhar com arrays no python, teria algumas dicas de como eu poderia fazer algo do tipo só que em python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre, pois depois da primeira vez que o usuário escolhe a opção do menu, a variável `option` não tem mais o seu valor alterado, e você está dentro de um `while True`.

Uma correção simples, seria colocar o trecho que solicita a opção de menu ao usuário dentro do `while True`:

```
while True:
    option = menu()
```

Com isso, o programa passaria a questionar o usuário novamente, permitindo assim escolher uma outra opção.

Então para sair do programa, você deverá implementar uma condição para a opção 4, permitindo assim sair do loop, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
while True:
    option = menu()

    if option == 1 :
        cadastra_cliente()
    if option == 2 :
        mostrar_cliente()
    if option == 4 :
      break
```

Veja que agora, além de sempre perguntar ao usuário qual opção ele deseja, existe uma condição que faz o `break` para sair do loop e assim finalizar o programa.

---

O código completo ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#cadastro de cliente em programacao procedural

clientes = []
n_clientes = 1

def menu() :
    option = int(input('''
[1] - Cadastrar cliente
[2] - Consultar Clientes
[3] - Editar Cliente
[4] - Sair do programa
'''))

    return option

def cadastra_cliente() :
    cliente_nome = input('Digite o nome do cliente: ')
    cliente_cep = input('Digite o cep do cliente: ')
    cliente_telefone = input('Digite o telefone do cliente: ')
    clientes_dados = (cliente_nome,cliente_cep,cliente_telefone)
    clientes.append(clientes_dados)
    print(clientes)
    print('Cliente adicionado')

def mostrar_cliente() :
    for cliente in clientes:
      print(f'''
      Nome: {cliente[0]}
      Cep: {cliente[1]}
      Telefone: {cliente[2]}''')


def programa() :

    while True:
        option = menu()

        if option == 1 :
            cadastra_cliente()
        if option == 2 :
            mostrar_cliente()
        if option == 4 :
          break

programa()
```

*Obs.: Eu fiz uma pequena alteração na função `mostrar_cliente`, ela estava gerando exceção, criei um loop simples, para iterar na variável `clientes` e assim exibir todos os clientes no console.*

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PlainGoldenrodProgram